# Pass SQL Connection to ActionListener (Thread)

Tags: java, sql, swing, actionlistener

How can I pass a SQL connection to a Action Listener.  I want to have an infinite loop, that sleeps for 100ms.  Every iteration the loop is suppose to query a database.  Is swing timer the best way to do this?  If so how can I pass the connection to the Action Listener.  If not, can someone please advise on how this can be done.  Much thanks.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AdminManager frame = new AdminManager();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        BoneCP connectionPool = null;
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            // setup the connection pool
            BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
            config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://192.162.0.0");
            config.setUsername("root"); 
            config.setPassword("");
            connectionPool = new BoneCP(config); // setup the connection pool

            connection = connectionPool.getConnection(); // fetch a connection

            if (connection != null){
                System.out.println("Connection successful!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        // Define listner
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //...Perform a task...

                String sql = "SELECT * table;";
                Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()) {
                    String symbol = rs.getString("name");
                    System.out.println(symbol);
                }

            }
            };
        Timer timer = new Timer( 100 , taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //connectionPool.shutdown(); // shutdown connection pool.
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `javax.swing.Timer`? I don't see where you're using any Swing components. Perhaps you should be using the `Executors`/`ScheduledExecutorService` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not the `javax.swing.Timer` class to periodically execute a non-Swing task. Instead, use a [`ScheduleExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html),

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.schedule(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // query database
    }
}, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: So I should put the ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); part in my main class and then put the rest of it in another method and call that method?

Comment: Okay, but how do I pass the connection into the ScheduledExecutorService?

Answer (score 1):

If the background task must continually update a Swing component, use `SwingWorker` to `process()` periodic updates to the component's model. In this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata), a `JTextArea` is updated with data obtained from an H2 database.